# lazy initialization exception, FetchType.EAGER

Tags: java, hibernate, dozer

I have a classical exception `LazyInitializationException`, but I have my entity and map as a field with annotation `FetchType.EAGER`

1) I have `UserDaoImpl` marked as `@Transactional` (`propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY`)

2) I have entity `User` , which has a map field

```
 @CollectionOfElements(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinTable(name ="SOME_TABLE_NAME", joinColumns =  
            @JoinColumn(name="SOME_COLUMN_NAME"))
 @MapKey(columns = @Column(name="SERVICE"))
 private Map<String, Integer> propertyName
```

3) `UserService`, which has the same method as `UserDao`, but marked as `@Transactional` . There I execute methods using `UserDaoImpl`, so I can get from `UserDAO` a `UserModel` and then I want to transform it to `UserDTO` and return.

When I debug this application in `UserService`, I get `userModel` which has this map properly initialized. To make this transformation I use Dozzer mapping. And here is a problem, because I get lazy initialization exception on this map (it was initialized before passing it to dozzer methods).

Why can I get lazy initialization exception having `FetchType.EAGER` ?

Comment: Have you gone through this?:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491949/dozer-hibernate-persistentmap-is-not-mapped-to-java-util-hashmap. You'll need to instantiate your map property in your DTO.

Comment: I didn't see this post, thanks, but is there another way of solving this problem ? Changing interface map to hashmap isn't very nice.

Comment: Actually, if you go through this post:http://sourceforge.net/p/dozer/discussion/452530/thread/bbffc31b, you will find out that `Dozer can not understand, which instance of Map interface implementation to instantiate and defaults to the source map subtype.`